# jQuery slideshow overlapping CSS ribbon

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm designing a website that has a CSS ribbon hanging from the top left corner. When I place an image under the ribbon, the ribbon overlaps the image, which is the look I'm going for.

[image: Ribbon is overlapping]

However, when I implement a J-Query slide show technique the following happens.

[image: Middle of transition]

[image: Ribbon is cut in half]

**My question is, how can I get the overlapping appearance I desire while being able to use the slide show? Below I've posted my code for the following.**

**HTML AND JAVASCRIPT FOR SLIDESHOW**

```html
    <center>

<div id="slideshow">
    <div>
      <img class="slide_img" src="images/limo_banner.png">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="slide_img" src="images/24_banner.png">
    </div>
    <div>
     <img class="slide_img" src="images/limo_banner.png">
    </div>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);

});

</script>

</center>
```

**CSS FOR SLIDESHOW**

```css
#slideshow {  
    position: relative;
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
}

.slide_img  {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
}
```

**CSS FOR RIBBON**

```css
.ribbon {
    background: #A83736;
    border-left: 1px dashed #aaa;
    border-right: 1px dashed #aaa;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 5px 0 0 #A83736, -5px 0 0 #A83736;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 90px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 2px 5px hsla(0,0%,0%,.5));
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.ribbon:after, .ribbon:before {
    border-top: 15px solid #A83736;
    content: '';
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 0;
}
.ribbon:after {
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    right: -6px;
}
.ribbon:before {
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    left: -6px;
}
```

Comment: did u try on ribbon z-index: 1 ?

Comment: no prob glad it works!

Comment: @AlexGarulli may as well post an answer if you want credit :)

Answer (score 3):

Set the ribbon to have a higher z-index than the slideshow containing div and it will show.

```
.ribbon { z-index 10; }

.containing-div-for-slideshow { z-index: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your ribbon z-index high: 9999. A lot of carousels and slideshows I have used set z-indexes on their elements.